# Coldfusion insert a href URL link into DB Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, coldfusion-9

i try to track all URL's as soon as a users click on a href and insert it to the oracle database, like a monitoring how many time this link has been used. What is the best way to do it? any idea/example to share? I'm new and trying to learn.. thank you so much for your help and support

Example:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" onClick="window.open(this.href);return false;" style = "padding-left:10px;color: black">stackoverflow</a><br>

<a href="https://google.com" onClick="window.open(this.href);return false;" style = "padding-left:10px;color: black">GOOGLE</a><br>

<cfquery name="url" datasource="test">
insert into url (url, date) values ('#url#, sysdate)
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way of tracking outbound links is to send the user to a page that tracks the click, then redirects them to the desired page:

```
<a href="/outbound.cfm?redirectURL=https://stackoverflow.com">
```

Your `outbound.cfm` page would handle calling a function to insert the metadata into your DB, as well as the redirect. You can get the `redirectURL` via the `attributes` scope.

As a side note, you should never use a `cfquery` without using `cfqueryparam`. As written, your query would be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: thx, in case you have time can you share an example cfquery and cfquerparma? thx.